Unable to understand what the error is here when trying to call a function
App.js:261 Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]
 (transactionHash="0x740cb13c2a900bcfad49cc23def231fea9e79f9b0dfb1eaaa24c1ea0ebbd902b", transaction={"hash":"0x740cb13c2a900bcfad49cc23def231fea9e79f9b0dfb1eaaa24c1ea0ebbd902b","type":2,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0x97156971C1ff38Fdc1f58f962eBfdb298Cf1d445","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1a8133b800"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1a8133b800"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1a8133b800"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x03d090"},"to":"0x1304B61FC6D519eF05B57f30d4928cD61fc0DA9d","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":87,"data":"0x6ffcc71900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015","r":"0x48bdd146babba4081105c21c7c1b7906770c7464312398d5131ee31b42618e50","s":"0x67ed5f848e46c1068cd0b18cceac9636f18cf68aa3bef28084f47ad6574542f7","v":0,"creates":null,"chainId":0}, receipt={"to":"0x1304B61FC6D519eF05B57f30d4928cD61fc0DA9d","from":"0x97156971C1ff38Fdc1f58f962eBfdb298Cf1d445","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":1,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xcf96"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000020000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000100000","blockHash":"0xb028882ccb7a1de84a8973c9448dbd17f0b94f2de2e7ee8fcf90a2e471d79120","transactionHash":"0x740cb13c2a900bcfad49cc23def231fea9e79f9b0dfb1eaaa24c1ea0ebbd902b","logs":[{"transactionIndex":1,"blockNumber":12915113,"transactionHash":"0x740cb13c2a900bcfad49cc23def231fea9e79f9b0dfb1eaaa24c1ea0ebbd902b","address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010","topics":
["0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010","0x00000000000000000000000097156971c1ff38fdc1f58f962ebfdb298cf1d445","0x00000000000000000000000009207a6efee346cb3e4a54ac18523e3715d38b3f"],
"data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000157e008609a636000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001348bd5f8bd0386420000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e95f16bebb19037288000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001347657f836f9e00c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e95f2c3cbb9f0d18be"
,"logIndex":7,
"blockHash":"0xb028882ccb7a1de84a8973c9448dbd17f0b94f2de2e7ee8fcf90a2e471d79120"}],"blockNumber":12915113,"confirmations":8,"cumulativeGasUsed":
{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x029ec2"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1a8133b800"},"status":0,"type":2,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)

I checked amoy.polygonscan and apparently the issue is that the contract is reverting just after approval to spend token.
This is my solildity contract-

pragma solidity 0.8.20;  
  
import "./Errors.sol";  
  
import { VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus } from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";  
import { IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus } from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/interfaces/IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus.sol";  
import { VRFV2PlusClient } from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";  
import { ReentrancyGuard } from "solady/src/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";  
import { IERC20 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";  
  
contract CoinFlip is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, ReentrancyGuard {  
    
  
   
   IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus internal immutable COORDINATOR;  
   bytes32 internal immutable KEY_HASH;  
   uint256 private immutable SUBSCRIPTION_ID;  
   uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;  
   uint32 private constant CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT = 1e5;  
   uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;  
  
   IERC20 public immutable betToken;  
   uint256 public constant MIN_BET = 1 * 10**18; // 1 token  
   uint256 public constant MAX_BET = 100 * 10**18; // 100 tokens  
   uint256 private contractBalance;  
  
   struct PlayerByAddress {  
      uint256 balance;  
      uint256 betAmount;  
      uint256 betChoice;  
      address playerAddress;  
      bool betOngoing;  
   }  
  
   struct Temp {  
      uint256 id;  
      uint256 result;  
      address playerAddress;  
   }  
  
    
   mapping(address => PlayerByAddress) public playersByAddress;  
  
   
   mapping(uint256 => Temp) public temps;  
  
   
  
   event DepositToContract(address indexed user, uint256 indexed depositAmount, uint256 newBalance);  
   event Withdrawal(address player, uint256 amount);  
   event NewIdRequest(address indexed player, uint256 requestId);  
   event GeneratedRandomNumber(uint256 requestId, uint256 randomNumber);  
   event BetResult(address indexed player, bool victory, uint256 amount);  
   event ContractBalanceWithdrawn(address indexed owner, uint256 amount);  
  
     
  
   constructor(  
      address _vrfCoordinator,  
      bytes32 _keyHash,  
      uint256 _subscriptionId,  
      address _betTokenAddress  
   ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator) {  
      COORDINATOR = IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator);  
      KEY_HASH = _keyHash;  
      SUBSCRIPTION_ID = _subscriptionId;  
      betToken = IERC20(_betTokenAddress);  
   }  
  
  
  
   
   function bet(uint256 _betChoice, uint256 _betAmount) public nonReentrant {  
      if (_betChoice != 0 && _betChoice != 1) revert CoinFlip__InvalidBetChoice();  
  
      address player = msg.sender;  
      PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];  
  
      if (_player.betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetAlreadyOngoing();  
  
      if (_betAmount < MIN_BET) revert CoinFlip__InsufficientAmount();  
      if (_betAmount > MAX_BET) revert CoinFlip__AmountTooBig();  
      if (_betAmount > getContractBalance() / 2) revert CoinFlip__AmountTooBig();  
  
      bool success = betToken.transferFrom(player, address(this), _betAmount);  
      if (!success) revert CoinFlip__TokenTransferFailed();  
  
      _player.playerAddress = player;  
      _player.betChoice = _betChoice;  
      _player.betOngoing = true;  
      _player.betAmount = _betAmount;  
  
      playersByAddress[player] = _player;  
      contractBalance += _betAmount;  
  
      uint256 requestId = requestRandomWords();  
      temps[requestId].playerAddress = player;  
      temps[requestId].id = requestId;  
  
      emit NewIdRequest(player, requestId);  
   }  
  
   
   function withdrawPlayerBalance() public nonReentrant {  
      address player = msg.sender;  
      if (playersByAddress[player].betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetOngoing();  
      if (playersByAddress[player].balance == 0) revert CoinFlip__NoFundsToWithdraw();  
  
      uint256 amount = playersByAddress[player].balance;  
      delete (playersByAddress[player]);  
  
      bool success = betToken.transfer(player, amount);  
      if (!success) revert CoinFlip__WithdrawFailed();  
  
      emit Withdrawal(player, amount);  
   }  
  
   
   function deposit(uint256 _amount) public {  
      if (_amount == 0) revert CoinFlip__InsufficientAmount();  
      bool success = betToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);  
      if (!success) revert CoinFlip__DepositFailed();  
      contractBalance += _amount;  
      emit DepositToContract(msg.sender, _amount, contractBalance);  
   }  
  
    
   function getPlayerBalance() public view returns (uint256) {  
      return playersByAddress[msg.sender].balance;  
   }  
  
    
   function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {  
      return betToken.balanceOf(address(this));  
   }  
  
   
   function getMinBet() public pure returns (uint256) {  
      return MIN_BET;  
   }  
  
   
   function getMaxBet() public pure returns (uint256) {  
      return MAX_BET;  
   }  
  
    
   function requestRandomWords() private returns (uint256) {  
      return  
        COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(  
           VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({  
              keyHash: KEY_HASH,  
              subId: SUBSCRIPTION_ID,  
              requestConfirmations: REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,  
              callbackGasLimit: CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT,  
              numWords: NUM_WORDS,  
              extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({ nativePayment: false }))  
           })  
        );  
   }  
  
   
   function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] calldata _randomWords) internal override {  
      uint256 randomResult = _randomWords[0] % 2;  
      temps[_requestId].result = randomResult;  
  
      checkResult(randomResult, _requestId);  
      emit GeneratedRandomNumber(_requestId, randomResult);  
   } 
    function checkResult(uint256 _randomResult, uint256 _requestId) private returns (bool) {
        address player = temps[_requestId].playerAddress;
        bool win = false;
        uint256 amountWon = 0;

        PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];

        if (_player.betChoice == _randomResult) {
            win = true;
            amountWon = _player.betAmount * 2;
            _player.balance += amountWon;
            contractBalance -= amountWon;
            _player.betOngoing = false;
        }

        _player.betAmount = 0;
        _player.betOngoing = false;
        playersByAddress[player] = _player;

        emit BetResult(player, win, amountWon);

        delete (temps[_requestId]);
        return win;
    }

   

    function withdrawContractBalance() public onlyOwner {
        if (contractBalance == 0) revert CoinFlip__NoFundsToWithdraw();

        uint256 toTransfer = contractBalance;
        contractBalance = 0;
        bool success = betToken.transfer(owner(), toTransfer);
        if (!success) revert CoinFlip__WithdrawFailed();

        emit ContractBalanceWithdrawn(owner(), toTransfer);
    }

    
    receive() external payable {
        
    }
}


What I noticed was that the transaction details on polygonscan and log show chainID:0 whereas I've used 80002
networks: {
    amoy:{
      url: polygonAmoyRpc,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      gasPrice: 30000000000, // 10 Gwei, adjust this value as necessary
      chainId: 80002,
    },
  },


Have you created a subscription at https://vrf.chain.link and added your contract address as a consumer there?

Yeah, I've done all that. I verified if I passed all the correct details on deploy script and it was all correct, So the issue isnt there.

I've tested your contract on Avalanche Fuji, the bet function is working fine. Here's the transaction trace on Tenderly. But the fulfillRandomWords from the subscription is getting reverted with Failed: gas limit set too low error. I'd even set the maximum callback gas limit i.e., 2_500_000. So, you might have to rewrite the logic inside fulfillRandomWords so as to decrease some computations, thereby decreasing the gas consumption by the same.

Do I just re assign the value for CALLBACK LIMIT? I can't seem to wrap my head around optimizing the logic of RandomWord functions.

I’ve already tested by setting CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT as the maximum i.e., 2_500_000, but still it’s reverting with the gas limit set too low error. But, you can try that on your end. Otherwise, you might have to rewrite the logic or split the logic into multiple functions.

I tried and I'm getting the same error. I'll give it a shot by writing multiple functions
